# iterm2: Any good way to clear a plain-text password from terminal screen without deleting entire scrollback?

Tags: linux, macos, iterm2

I occasionally need to set env vars with passwords or pin numbers or the like, and they appear in my backscroll.  No one looks at my terminal or anything, but it would be nice to be able to clear my password or pin number from the screen without the nuclear `clear` option removing all of my backscroll.

I've done some searching: carriage returns don't really work in iterm like we'd expect them to, and control+L just moves everything off screen instead of actually deleting it from the history.

Comment: Based on the existing post and answers, this does not appear to be currently implemented.